# How to add a sentence to the enter entry and before return instruction of all the functions of my project . Thanks

Tags: linux, function, gcc, vim

I want to print some useful message after entering or returning functions by adding the following sentence.

```
printf("enter %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
```

Add the following sentence before return instruction.

```
printf("exit %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
```

My OS is ubuntu. I think vim can do this work. Editing before return instruction is easy. However, to the first case, finding the first line of every function is not easy . 
Can gcc do this work during the precompiled period ? 
Can any one help me . 
Thanks very much.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? I feel like this information could be obtained with a debugger.

Comment: Sometimes I just want to trace the project.  Or sometimes to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: How big a project are we talking about and what style of code are you using? (Post a sample?)

Comment: Not more than 20 files, and about 200 functions.

Comment: The code is too long, hard to post here.

Comment: So to do this in vim you would probably want to define some pattern that represents the beginning of a function and some pattern that represents the end of the function. Without knowing the style I can not come up with these patterns. But you probably want to take a look at `:h :global` and `:h :normal` to do this. And maybe `:h :bufdo` or `:h :argdo` to do this on all of the files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering an editor-based approach.

You could also consider a compiler based approach. You could extend GCC using your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension which would add a pass. This pass would just have to add some extra Gimple into the GCC internal representations.

Comment: Oh, I have never heard about it. It seems hard to me.